# why is this javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to build a function for adding bread crumbs to my site's navigation. However, right now I have two problems. 1) For some reason the crumb array only holds 2 crumbs at a time, and 2), even though the html elements are stored in the crumbs array, only the new crumb's HTML is rendered. The other crumb renders as:

```
[object HTMLLIElement]
```

// script

```
function add_crumb(name) {

    // get current bread crumbs
    var crumbs = $('#breadcrumbs ul li').toArray();

    // no current bread crumbs, so we don't need an arrow image
    if (crumbs.length == 0) {

        var new_crumb = "<li class='crumb' style='display:inline'> " + name + " </li>";

    } else {

        var new_crumb = "<li class='crumb' style='display:inline'><img class='bc_arrow' src='images/icons/breadcrumb_arrow.png' width='19' height='18'> " + name + "</li>";

    }

    // add new bread crumb to array
    crumbs.push(new_crumb);

    // render
    $('#breadcrumbs').html('<ul>' + crumbs.join('') + '</ul>');


}
```

Anyways, I've side stepped the second problem by creating a new blank array and calling .innerHTML on each element (even though I don't understand why I have to do this since jQuery's site says the elements are stored like so:

```
[<li id="foo">, <li id="bar">]
```

But if someone could please help me figure out why it's only storing two bread crumbs at a time, I would really, really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML Element Objects are not strings, you cannot simply concat them to a string using `.join`. Try appending them.

```
$('#breadcrumbs').html('<ul />').find("ul").append(crumbs);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('#breadcrumbs ul li').toArray();` gives you an array of [HTMLLIElements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLLIElement).

You should take a different approach altogether.  No need for any arrays:

```
if($('#breadcrumbs ul li').length){
    $('#breadcrumbs ul').append(
      "<li class='crumb' style='display:inline'>"
        + name +
      "</li>");
}else{
    $('#breadcrumbs ul').append(
      "<li class='crumb' style='display:inline'>"
        + "<img class='bc_arrow' src='images/icons/breadcrumb_arrow.png' width='19' height='18'>" +
        + name + 
      "</li>");
}
```